# Requirement Management and Eclipse Papyrus

Tags: eclipse, papyrus

I have a weird question, back at the day, 2011ish I think, before Topcased become Eclipse Papyrus, there was functionality in Topcased to relate Requirement Management  - Requirements to the UML Diagram, for ex, to link a requirement to an UML Class so later on we can identify because of which requirement, actually that UML Class exist.

Well it is a long time from 2011 and I can't exactly remember under which feature this was implemented in Topcased and it is immigrated to Eclipse Papyrus at all....

When I search for Requirement Management and Eclipse Papyrus, I encounter SysML Profile but I am not sure this is what I want...

Did the Requirement Management part of the Topcased migrated to Eclipse Papyrus at all?

Or let me ask this way, what are you doing if you want to relate your requirements to UML Model?

Thx for answers